# Fixed position navigation bar not full width of the window overlaps links etc

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a fixed position navigation bar that is not the full width of the window and that is not attached to the browser window. So at max-width 1200px it stops and stays there and not follows the right border of the browser and below 1200px it is attached to the right side of the browser to fit the window.

The code below achieves what I just described except it does not allow user to click link that is next to the navigation bar "clickable". That is because of `max-width:1200px` and `width: 100%` which forces my navigation bar to overlap anything else on that page and I would like to fix that somehow.

```css
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
#navigation svg {
  float: right;
}
#navigation svg polyline {
  fill: #F7F7F7;
  stroke: #B9D7D9;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
#navigation ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0.8rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
#navigation li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <svg height="50" width="400">
    <polyline points="0,0 400,0 400,50 70,50 0,0" />
  </svg>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<a href="#">Clickable</a>
```

Here is what I want to happen over 1200px window:
[image]

Less than 1200px window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using @media queries for different layouts regarding the size of your screen? see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Maybe this css code could solve your problem

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
    #navigation {
        width:80%;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #navigation{
        width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: The problem with percentages is that it would not stop at max 1200px whatever the 80% of users resultion would be. My site is 1200 px wide so I would like the navigation bar to stop at 1200px.

Answer (score 0):

The `clickable` link is not clickable because its `z-index` is below the `#navigations`.
To fix this you can use the following style (I use the class `.clickable` in this example).
Additionaly for proper centering on screens with more than 1200px width you can add some more positioning to `#navigation` to center it properly.

```css
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  
  /* Center #navigation (dont forget vendor prefixes for transform)*/
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
}
#navigation svg {
  float: right;
}
#navigation svg polyline {
  fill: #F7F7F7;
  stroke: #B9D7D9;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
#navigation ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0.8rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
#navigation li {
  float: left;
}

.clickable{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <svg height="50" width="400">
    <polyline points="0,0 400,0 400,50 70,50 0,0" />
  </svg>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<a href="#" class="clickable">Clickable</a>
```

Comment: That is not a solution it will make a link clickable but the rest of my site will be visible through navigation bar which does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem. Since my max-width is 1200px and navigation is 400px wide I need to push it to the right 800px.

If the screen is wider than 1200px I push the navigation bar 800 px right and if screen is smaller than 1200 px right: 0 which means navigation bar will be attached to the browser.

```
#navigation{
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    right: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    #navigation{
        margin-left:800px!important;
        right: initial;
    }
}
```